# Kafka security and authentication

Tags: apache-kafka, iot

We are trying to make Kafka for public accessible.Does Kafka support SSL connection? Is there possible to authenticate client connection?
Please share some idea's to implement..

Comment: If such a need justifies, use ssh-auth / ssh-certificate-management + use ssh-port-forwarding to get the user access both secure & auth'ed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Security wasn't part of Apache Kafka's original goal. However it is planned to implement authentication and authorization in the future. You can have a look here: [Apache Kafka Security](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Security).

Answer (score 3):

SSL security is supported starting from 0.9.x, so it's possible to authenticate client's connection based on CN name in SSL certificate and ACL settings for the topic.
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Deploying+SSL+for+Kafka